# in R: turn list of functions into one big function (element-wise sum of functions)

Tags: r, list, function

I have list of functions, which I would like to add up to one "big" function. Example:

```
funlist=list()  
funlist[[1]]=exp(x1)
funlist[[2]]=sin(x2)
```

Desired outcome:

```
bigfun = exp(x1) + sin(x2)
```

I know for numeric cases one could use `reduce("+", list)`, but what about non-numeric cases as above?

Please note: I am looking for a general automated solution, that is,  the list of functions may vary (functions itself and length of list/ number of functions), but  all functions of the list must be added to one final term in the end. Each function should have its own value that must be provided (e.g. x1 to funlist[[1]], x2 to funlist[[2]] etc).

IMPORTANT: the bigfun term is then passed on to an optimizer (optim) to find the best values for each function that maximize the outcome of all functions together.

EDIT:
I chose the fucntions exp(x1) and sin(x2) for simplicity. The functions are function wrappers themselves, eg
function(x) {y1*x + y2*x^2 + y3*x^3} , whereby y1, y2, y3 have been calculated before.

Comment: `f <- function(x) sin(x) + exp(x)` then e.g. `f(0.5)`.

Comment: Thanks for posting, but unfortunately this is not a generalizable solution that can be applied to varying functions (I further edited my text to make it clearer).

Comment: Yes I saw. Bens solution seems appropriate to me in that case. Hope it was what you were looking for. Good question BTW. +1.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Ben's idea was in the right direction, but not completely what I was looking for yet.

Comment: Please post the optimization problem.

Comment: `optim` would find the optimal values of `vec`, given a list `funs` that you supply.

Comment: Ben: the functions are supposed to be provided to optim, thus that i find solutions for x1, x2, etc that maximize the objective function [e.g. each function represents different inputs (output/input described by the function) that I can influence]

Comment: Your question is very confusing because when you write something like `funlist[[1]]=exp(x1)`, you really mean a function: `funlist[[1]]=function(x1)exp(x1)`. They are two very different things in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a functional programming approach where you store your functions in a list.

```
funs <- c(sin,exp)

bigfun<-function(x,funs){
sum(sapply(funs, function(f) f(x)))}

bigfun(x=10,funs=funs)
```

Learned this from Hadley Wickham:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#lists-of-functions

**EDIT**To supply multiple values (i.e. different value for each function):

```
bigfun2<-function(vec,funs){vf<-function(vec,funs){funs(vec)} 
sum(sapply(1:length(vec),function (i) vf(vec[i],funs[[i]])))}

optim(par=initvec,fn=bigfun2,funs=funs)
```

This assumes you have a list of functions equal to the length of your data vector, where `funs` is your function list and `vec` is your data vector. In the optimization example, just set a vector `initvec` with inital starting values of equal length to `funs`, which is passed as an additional param to `optim`

Comment: Thanks Ben. Almost there. However, does not this require all functions to be like funs? Funs cannot be part of the function, as it varies.

Comment: you can make it one of bigfun's arguments pretty easily. one sec

Comment: Take a look now; you can store your functions in a list and supply the list as an argument to `bigfun`

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your efforts. I guess I did not explain the issue  well enough (I edited my original question). While you can provide the functions to the function wrapper "bigfun", the values (in your example "x") should not be passed on (which also should vary for each function). I need bigfun to be a functional generizable term (as this is used for optim). If this makes sense.

Comment: Take a look at the solution below

Comment: Ben, thanks, you made the case generizable in that one can enter any value to vec and provide funs. But does not your code just apply the vector values to the function and then sums it up? Hence one always requires vec and funs. Please understand that the goal is to pass on the bigfun term (the different functions of the list) to an optimizer. Hence, the solution (function wrapper) cannot require a vector/ data input.

Comment: what are you trying to optimize? You do not have to pass a fixed data vector to optim, you just set initial values

Comment: I think I just understood your triple-nested function now, Ben. Nice work! I still need to test whether it works with optim, but it actually should if I understand it now (and my test worked). Thanks again (once I have the result, I will update everyone, e.g. accept the answer).

Comment: Ben takes the cake... all working as supposed to (including optim). Thanks again Ben! Good work with the triple-nested function.

Comment: Ben, after a while I need to come back to this? Is it possible that the model above assumes that the third part (funs=funs) is the gradient? I am getting some weird results. Also, when I tried to provide the gradient and the function, it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a functional that will take a list of functions and return a function computing their sum:

```
add.funs <- function(funlist) {
   function(...) Reduce(`+`, lapply(funlist, do.call, as.list(...)))
}
```

For example:

```
funlist=list()  
funlist[[1]] <- function(x) {5*x + 2*x^2 + 3*x^3}
funlist[[2]] <- function(x)sin(x)

bigfun <- add.funs(funlist)

bigfun(3)
# [1] 114.1411
```

which is indeed the same as:

```
funlist[[1]](3) + funlist[[2]](3)
# [1] 114.1411
```

---

Edit: For a single distinct argument per function, try this:

```
add.funs <- function(funlist) {
   function(...) {
      arglist <- lapply(as.list(...), as.list)
      Reduce(`+`, Map(do.call, funlist, arglist))
   }
}

bigfun <- add.funs(funlist)

bigfun(c(3, 4))
# [1] 113.2432
funlist[[1]](3) + funlist[[2]](4)
# [1] 113.2432
```

Comment: Thanks flodel. Haven't tested this solution, as I would need different input for each function (I know one could extend your approach, similar to Ben's nested functions). Therefore, I have accepted Ben's answer.

Comment: I can improve. Can you clarify: does each function take a single, distinct argument?

Comment: Yes, you are right, each function takes a single, distinct argument (x1, x2, ..).

Comment: +1. Nice work Flodel, thanks! Learnt something new (MAP). In the name of fairness, I keep Ben's answer as the accepted one, since he was the first to provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

Lets say that the functions are stored as strings:

```
funlist=list()  
funlist[[1]]="exp(x)"
funlist[[2]]="sin(x)"
```

You can combine the strings, and then parse + eval:

```
eval(parse(text=paste("bigfun <- function(x)", do.call(paste,c(funlist,sep="+")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

See, also, something like:

```
make_bigfun <- function(..., sep = " + ") {
   funlist = list(...)

   ff = function() NULL
   environment(ff) = parent.frame()

   formals(ff) = unlist(lapply(funlist, formals)) 
   body(ff) = parse(text = do.call(paste, c(lapply(funlist, function(x) deparse(body(x))), sep = sep)))

   return(ff)
}

make_bigfun(function(x1) exp(x1), function(x2) sin(x2), function(x3) cos(x3))
#function (x1, x2, x3) 
#exp(x1) + sin(x2) + cos(x3)
do.call(make_bigfun, c(list(function(x1) exp(x1), function(x2) sin(x2)), sep = " - "))
#function (x1, x2) 
#exp(x1) - sin(x2)
bigfun = make_bigfun(function(x1) exp(x1), function(x2) sin(x2))
identical(exp(1) + sin(2), bigfun(1,2))
#[1] TRUE
```